# Form groups with must-include and must-exclude constraints

Tags: graph-theory

Given a set of vertices $V$, and for each $v \in V$, two sets of vertices $Y_v$ and $N_v$ where $Y_v \subseteq V$ and $N_v \subseteq V$.

Determine if it is possible to form one or more subsets of $V$ so that each vertex is used exactly once (can't reuse; and each $v$ must be in some subset of $V$), and for each $v'$ in each subset $S$, $\forall y_{v'}\in Y_{v'}, y_{v'} \in S$ (all vertices in must-include list of any vertex must exist in the same subset as that vertex) and $\forall n_{v'}\in N_{v'}, n_{v'} \notin S$ (all vertices in must-exclude list of any vertex must not exist in the same subset as that vertex).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Define $v \rhd u \iff u \in Y_v$ and let $v \diamond u$ be its reflexive, symmetric, transitive closure.
- Check if $[v]_\diamond$, the equivalence class of $v$ with regard to $\diamond$ satisfies $[v]_\diamond \cap N_v = \varnothing$ for every $v \in V$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$